# Kafka schema registry helm chart cant connect to AWS MSK because of connection timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, confluent-schema-registry, aws-msk

We have a kuberntes cluster on AWS EKS and have pods deployed in it. And we have a AWS MSK kafka service in the same VPC.
I can connect to MSK service from my pods and can produce/consume messages.
I'm trying to install a schema registry via confluent's helm chart in my Kubernetes cluster. But it can't connect to my kafka service, I couldn't figure out the reason. Has anyone an idea?

I'm using [cp-schema-registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-schema-registry) helm chart.

Here is my installation command

```
helm install --set kafka.bootstrapServers="SSL://b-1.broker-address.kafka.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9094\,SSL://b-2.broker-address.kafka.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9094" schema-broker cp-helm-charts/charts/cp-schema-registry
```

And this is the error in the schema registry pod.

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 6.1.0-ccs
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 5496d92defc9bbe4
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1639997224270
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1639997254287, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1639997254410) timed out at 1639997254310 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata
[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Error while getting broker list.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1639997264296, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1639997264417) timed out at 1639997264317 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus.isKafkaReady(ClusterStatus.java:149)
    at io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand.main(KafkaReadyCommand.java:150)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1639997264296, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1639997264417) timed out at 1639997264317 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
[main] INFO io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Trying to query Kafka for metadata again ...
[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Brokers found [].
```

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue. Using the same version of schema-registry too. This was working on and off last week too. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: Try specifying `security.protocol=SSL` explicitly and remove `SSL://` from the bootstrap server URL. Had similar issue with `IAM`